# How to easily beat Eraqus?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep

I have been playing BBS for the past 2 days and now I'm with the scenario of Terra. Am I the only one who doesn't manage to beat Eraqus? I had no difficulty to beat Zack, once you know how to avoid his Omnislash it's not a big deal. I don't want to waste my time at leveling, I guess there is a simple way to defeat him. So here are my questions :

**Which elements are his weak point ?**
**Which shoot capacity should I use to deal huge damage ?**
**Is there a D-Link I could use to beat him ?**

I know this may have been answered on some random wiki, but I want to hear that from players

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to beat him (don't know why I didn't succed before) so here are answers for those who whant them :

Weak point : Didn't find out, but he is resistant to darkness.
Dealing huge damage with shoot capacity : Lightning beam.
Can't use D-Link when you fight him.

---

I don't know if someone care here, but here is a solution to beat him easily :
When you arrive in the battle, just attack him until the final attack of your transformation, step back and use your lightning beam grouped shot. Dodge his attacks and strike back, until you transform again. Do the same until you beat him.

---

Well... I found this boss quite difficult, but I was in proud mode and my level was quite low.